# angularjs - [$injector:modulerr] error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Batch editable table</title>



    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/v0.8.1/dist/ng-table.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='css/nqjzro.css'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">




  </head>

  <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="page-header">Batch editable table</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info">
            <h4>Overview</h4>
            <p>Example of how to create a batch editable table.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-warning">
            <h4>Notice</h4>
            <p>There are several directives in use that track dirty state and validity of the table rows. Whilst they are reasonally capable they are <em>not production tested - use at your own risk!</em> <a href="#" ng-click="isExplanationOpen = !isExplanationOpen">More details...</a></p>
            <div ng-show="isExplanationOpen">
              <p>If you look at the declarative markup for the <code>ngTable</code> you'll see a bunch of nested <code>ngForm</code> directives, with a common ancestor <code>ngForm</code> at the level of the table element. Each nested <code>ngForm</code>                propogates their <code>$dirty</code> and <code>$invalid</code> state to this top level <code>ngForm</code>. This works great as you can enable/disable the buttons for saving the table based on the status of this single top-level <code>ngForm</code>.</p>
              <p>This works up till the point that the user select's a new page to display in the table. At which point the existing nested <code>ngForm</code> directives are swapped out for new instances as the new data page is loaded. These new <code>ngForm</code>                directives are always pristine and valid and this status propogates setting the corrosponding state on the top-level to be pristine and valid even though rows from the previous page are dirty and possibly invalid.</p>
              <p>The solution is to have a set of directives that sit parallel to the <code>ngForm</code> directives that remember the state of the rows when the corrosponding <code>ngFrom</code> directives are destroyed and recreated. When <code>ngForm</code>                directives are recreated they have their status reset by the directives that have remembered this state.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="demoController as demo">
      <h3>ngTable directive</h3>
      <div class="brn-group pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-if="demo.isEditing" ng-click="demo.cancelChanges()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="!demo.isEditing" ng-click="demo.isEditing = true">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="demo.isEditing" ng-disabled="!demo.hasChanges() || demo.tableTracker.$invalid" ng-click="demo.saveChanges()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="demo.add()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed editable-table" ng-form="demo.tableForm" disable-filter="demo.isAdding" demo-tracked-table="demo.tableTracker">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="70%" />
          <col width="12%" />
          <col width="13%" />
          <col width="5%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data" ng-form="rowForm" demo-tracked-table-row="row">
          <td title="'Name'" filter="{name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'" ng-switch="demo.isEditing" ng-class="name.$dirty ? 'bg-warning' : ''" ng-form="name" demo-tracked-table-cell>
            <span ng-switch-default class="editable-text">{{row.name}}</span>
            <div class="controls" ng-class="name.$invalid && name.$dirty ? 'has-error' : ''" ng-switch-when="true">
              <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="row.name" class="editable-input form-control input-sm" required />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td title="'Age'" filter="{age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'" ng-switch="demo.isEditing" ng-class="age.$dirty ? 'bg-warning' : ''" ng-form="age" demo-tracked-table-cell>
            <span ng-switch-default class="editable-text">{{row.age}}</span>
            <div class="controls" ng-class="age.$invalid && age.$dirty ? 'has-error' : ''" ng-switch-when="true">
              <input type="number" name="age" ng-model="row.age" class="editable-input form-control input-sm" required/>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td title="'Money'" filter="{money: 'number'}" sortable="'money'" ng-switch="demo.isEditing" ng-class="money.$dirty ? 'bg-warning' : ''" ng-form="money" demo-tracked-table-cell>
            <span ng-switch-default class="editable-text">{{row.money}}</span>
            <div class="controls" ng-class="money.$invalid && money.$dirty ? 'has-error' : ''" ng-switch-when="true">
              <input type="number" name="money" ng-model="row.money" class="editable-input form-control input-sm" required/>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="demo.del(row)" ng-disabled="!demo.isEditing"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="dynamicDemoController as demo">
      <h3>ngTableDynamic directive</h3>
      <div class="brn-group pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-if="demo.isEditing" ng-click="demo.cancelChanges()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="!demo.isEditing" ng-click="demo.isEditing = true">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="demo.isEditing" ng-disabled="!demo.hasChanges() || demo.tableTracker.$invalid" ng-click="demo.saveChanges()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="demo.add()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <table ng-table-dynamic="demo.tableParams with demo.cols" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover editable-table" ng-form="demo.tableForm" disable-filter="demo.isAdding" demo-tracked-table="demo.tableTracker">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="70%" />
          <col width="12%" />
          <col width="13%" />
          <col width="5%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data" ng-form="rowForm" demo-tracked-table-row="row">
          <td ng-repeat="col in $columns" ng-class="rowForm[col.field].$dirty ? 'bg-warning' : ''" ng-form="{{col.field}}" demo-tracked-table-cell>
            <span ng-if="col.dataType !== 'command' && !demo.isEditing" class="editable-text">{{row[col.field]}}</span>
            <div ng-if="col.dataType !== 'command' && demo.isEditing" class="controls" ng-class="rowForm[col.field].$invalid && rowForm[col.field].$dirty ? 'has-error' : ''" ng-switch="col.dataType">
              <input ng-switch-default type="text" name="{{col.field}}" ng-model="row[col.field]" class="editable-input form-control input-sm" required />
              <input ng-switch-when="number" type="number" name="{{col.field}}" ng-model="row[col.field]" class="editable-input form-control input-sm" required />
            </div>
            <button ng-if="col.dataType === 'command'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="demo.del(row)" ng-disabled="!demo.isEditing"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js'></script>


        <script src="js/index.js"></script>



    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular-route.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

> The above is  html code

```
    angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable", "ngTableDemos"]);

(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module("myApp").controller("demoController", demoController);
  demoController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "ngTableSimpleList"];

  function demoController(NgTableParams, simpleList) {
    var self = this;

    var originalData = angular.copy(simpleList);

    self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
      dataset: angular.copy(simpleList)
    });

    self.deleteCount = 0;

    self.add = add;
    self.cancelChanges = cancelChanges;
    self.del = del;
    self.hasChanges = hasChanges;
    self.saveChanges = saveChanges;

    //////////

    function add() {
      self.isEditing = true;
      self.isAdding = true;
      self.tableParams.settings().dataset.unshift({
        name: "",
        age: null,
        money: null
      });
      // we need to ensure the user sees the new row we've just added.
      // it seems a poor but reliable choice to remove sorting and move them to the first page
      // where we know that our new item was added to
      self.tableParams.sorting({});
      self.tableParams.page(1);
      self.tableParams.reload();
    }

    function cancelChanges() {
      resetTableStatus();
      var currentPage = self.tableParams.page();
      self.tableParams.settings({
        dataset: angular.copy(originalData)
      });
      // keep the user on the current page when we can
      if (!self.isAdding) {
        self.tableParams.page(currentPage);
      }
    }

    function del(row) {
      _.remove(self.tableParams.settings().dataset, function(item) {
        return row === item;
      });
      self.deleteCount++;
      self.tableTracker.untrack(row);
      self.tableParams.reload().then(function(data) {
        if (data.length === 0 && self.tableParams.total() > 0) {
          self.tableParams.page(self.tableParams.page() - 1);
          self.tableParams.reload();
        }
      });
    }

    function hasChanges() {
      return self.tableForm.$dirty || self.deleteCount > 0
    }

    function resetTableStatus() {
      self.isEditing = false;
      self.isAdding = false;
      self.deleteCount = 0;
      self.tableTracker.reset();
      self.tableForm.$setPristine();
    }

    function saveChanges() {
      resetTableStatus();
      var currentPage = self.tableParams.page();
      originalData = angular.copy(self.tableParams.settings().dataset);
    }
  }
})();

(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module("myApp").controller("dynamicDemoController", dynamicDemoController);
  dynamicDemoController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "ngTableSimpleList"];

  function dynamicDemoController(NgTableParams, simpleList) {
    var self = this;

    var originalData = angular.copy(simpleList);

    self.cols = [{
      field: "name",
      title: "Name",
      filter: {
        name: "text"
      },
      sortable: "name",
      dataType: "text"
    }, {
      field: "age",
      title: "Age",
      filter: {
        age: "number"
      },
      sortable: "age",
      dataType: "number"
    }, {
      field: "money",
      title: "Money",
      filter: {
        money: "number"
      },
      sortable: "money",
      dataType: "number"
    }, {
      field: "action",
      title: "",
      dataType: "command"
    }];
    self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
      dataset: angular.copy(simpleList)
    });

    self.deleteCount = 0;

    self.add = add;
    self.cancelChanges = cancelChanges;
    self.del = del;
    self.hasChanges = hasChanges;
    self.saveChanges = saveChanges;

    //////////

    function add() {
      self.isEditing = true;
      self.isAdding = true;
      self.tableParams.settings().dataset.unshift({
        name: "",
        age: null,
        money: null
      });
      // we need to ensure the user sees the new row we've just added.
      // it seems a poor but reliable choice to remove sorting and move them to the first page
      // where we know that our new item was added to
      self.tableParams.sorting({});
      self.tableParams.page(1);
      self.tableParams.reload();
    }

    function cancelChanges() {
      resetTableStatus();
      var currentPage = self.tableParams.page();
      self.tableParams.settings({
        dataset: angular.copy(originalData)
      });
      // keep the user on the current page when we can
      if (!self.isAdding) {
        self.tableParams.page(currentPage);
      }
    }

    function del(row) {
      _.remove(self.tableParams.settings().dataset, function(item) {
        return row === item;
      });
      self.deleteCount++;
      self.tableTracker.untrack(row);
      self.tableParams.reload().then(function(data) {
        if (data.length === 0 && self.tableParams.total() > 0) {
          self.tableParams.page(self.tableParams.page() - 1);
          self.tableParams.reload();
        }
      });
    }

    function hasChanges() {
      return self.tableForm.$dirty || self.deleteCount > 0
    }

    function resetTableStatus() {
      self.isEditing = false;
      self.isAdding = false;
      self.deleteCount = 0;
      self.tableTracker.reset();
      self.tableForm.$setPristine();
    }

    function saveChanges() {
      resetTableStatus();
      var currentPage = self.tableParams.page();
      originalData = angular.copy(self.tableParams.settings().dataset);
    }
  }
})();


(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module("myApp").run(configureDefaults);
  configureDefaults.$inject = ["ngTableDefaults"];

  function configureDefaults(ngTableDefaults) {
    ngTableDefaults.params.count = 5;
    ngTableDefaults.settings.counts = [];
  }
})();

/**********
  The following directives are necessary in order to track dirty state and validity of the rows 
  in the table as the user pages within the grid
------------------------
*/

(function() {
  angular.module("myApp").directive("demoTrackedTable", demoTrackedTable);

  demoTrackedTable.$inject = [];

  function demoTrackedTable() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      priority: -1,
      require: "ngForm",
      controller: demoTrackedTableController
    };
  }

  demoTrackedTableController.$inject = ["$scope", "$parse", "$attrs", "$element"];

  function demoTrackedTableController($scope, $parse, $attrs, $element) {
    var self = this;
    var tableForm = $element.controller("form");
    var dirtyCellsByRow = [];
    var invalidCellsByRow = [];

    init();

    ////////

    function init() {
      var setter = $parse($attrs.demoTrackedTable).assign;
      setter($scope, self);
      $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        setter(null);
      });

      self.reset = reset;
      self.isCellDirty = isCellDirty;
      self.setCellDirty = setCellDirty;
      self.setCellInvalid = setCellInvalid;
      self.untrack = untrack;
    }

    function getCellsForRow(row, cellsByRow) {
      return _.find(cellsByRow, function(entry) {
        return entry.row === row;
      })
    }

    function isCellDirty(row, cell) {
      var rowCells = getCellsForRow(row, dirtyCellsByRow);
      return rowCells && rowCells.cells.indexOf(cell) !== -1;
    }

    function reset() {
      dirtyCellsByRow = [];
      invalidCellsByRow = [];
      setInvalid(false);
    }

    function setCellDirty(row, cell, isDirty) {
      setCellStatus(row, cell, isDirty, dirtyCellsByRow);
    }

    function setCellInvalid(row, cell, isInvalid) {
      setCellStatus(row, cell, isInvalid, invalidCellsByRow);
      setInvalid(invalidCellsByRow.length > 0);
    }

    function setCellStatus(row, cell, value, cellsByRow) {
      var rowCells = getCellsForRow(row, cellsByRow);
      if (!rowCells && !value) {
        return;
      }

      if (value) {
        if (!rowCells) {
          rowCells = {
            row: row,
            cells: []
          };
          cellsByRow.push(rowCells);
        }
        if (rowCells.cells.indexOf(cell) === -1) {
          rowCells.cells.push(cell);
        }
      } else {
        _.remove(rowCells.cells, function(item) {
          return cell === item;
        });
        if (rowCells.cells.length === 0) {
          _.remove(cellsByRow, function(item) {
            return rowCells === item;
          });
        }
      }
    }

    function setInvalid(isInvalid) {
      self.$invalid = isInvalid;
      self.$valid = !isInvalid;
    }

    function untrack(row) {
      _.remove(invalidCellsByRow, function(item) {
        return item.row === row;
      });
      _.remove(dirtyCellsByRow, function(item) {
        return item.row === row;
      });
      setInvalid(invalidCellsByRow.length > 0);
    }
  }
})();

(function() {
  angular.module("myApp").directive("demoTrackedTableRow", demoTrackedTableRow);

  demoTrackedTableRow.$inject = [];

  function demoTrackedTableRow() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      priority: -1,
      require: ["^demoTrackedTable", "ngForm"],
      controller: demoTrackedTableRowController
    };
  }

  demoTrackedTableRowController.$inject = ["$attrs", "$element", "$parse", "$scope"];

  function demoTrackedTableRowController($attrs, $element, $parse, $scope) {
    var self = this;
    var row = $parse($attrs.demoTrackedTableRow)($scope);
    var rowFormCtrl = $element.controller("form");
    var trackedTableCtrl = $element.controller("demoTrackedTable");

    self.isCellDirty = isCellDirty;
    self.setCellDirty = setCellDirty;
    self.setCellInvalid = setCellInvalid;

    function isCellDirty(cell) {
      return trackedTableCtrl.isCellDirty(row, cell);
    }

    function setCellDirty(cell, isDirty) {
      trackedTableCtrl.setCellDirty(row, cell, isDirty)
    }

    function setCellInvalid(cell, isInvalid) {
      trackedTableCtrl.setCellInvalid(row, cell, isInvalid)
    }
  }
})();

(function() {
  angular.module("myApp").directive("demoTrackedTableCell", demoTrackedTableCell);

  demoTrackedTableCell.$inject = [];

  function demoTrackedTableCell() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      priority: -1,
      scope: true,
      require: ["^demoTrackedTableRow", "ngForm"],
      controller: demoTrackedTableCellController
    };
  }

  demoTrackedTableCellController.$inject = ["$attrs", "$element", "$scope"];

  function demoTrackedTableCellController($attrs, $element, $scope) {
    var self = this;
    var cellFormCtrl = $element.controller("form");
    var cellName = cellFormCtrl.$name;
    var trackedTableRowCtrl = $element.controller("demoTrackedTableRow");

    if (trackedTableRowCtrl.isCellDirty(cellName)) {
      cellFormCtrl.$setDirty();
    } else {
      cellFormCtrl.$setPristine();
    }
    // note: we don't have to force setting validaty as angular will run validations
    // when we page back to a row that contains invalid data

    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return cellFormCtrl.$dirty;
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue === oldValue) return;

      trackedTableRowCtrl.setCellDirty(cellName, newValue);
    });

    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return cellFormCtrl.$invalid;
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue === oldValue) return;

      trackedTableRowCtrl.setCellInvalid(cellName, newValue);
    });
  }
})();
```

> This is javascript file
>   The above code is angularjs. It displays table loading data with add row, delete, edit. 
>   Please solve this. Am getting error [$injector:modulerr] . Please help me to solve

Comment: Try changing function demoController(NgTableParams, ngTableSimpleList) {

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** They created different codepen for `ngTableDemos` [look here](http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/NqJzRo)

To run your sample you need to load that `ngTableDemos` related code first then your sample.

For codepen, to understand what are the files they are using to run any sample check **Pen Setting JavaScript tab** carefully.

---

Probably you didn't load `"ngTableDemos"` module, so if it is needed load associate file or remove it like

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"]);
```

Comment: I found the above code here - http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/MwdLmx   There it is working. But while customizing not working